# Refactoring Python Code in Function Calculating Jaccard Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, profiling

I have created a function that calculates the Jaccard index for a specific category and term. The function is supposed to find all the document ids that are connected to the term,category and then by using the formula J(T, C) = |DOC(T) ∩ DOC(C)| / |DOC(T) ∪ DOC(C)| we find the Jaccard index of this pair.

I have managed to run it (5 seconds), but have some issues with refactoring to make it run faster.I have hit a deadlock having tried everything in my current knowledge.

```
def calculate_j(tid, cid) -> float:
    doct = dids_via_tid(tid)
    docc = dids_via_category(cid)
      
    it1, it2 = tee(doct)
    it3, it4 = tee(docc)

    doc_either = dids_via_either(it1, it3)
    doc_both = dids_via_both(it2, it4)

    j = float(float(len(doc_both)) / float(len(doc_either)))
    return j

def dids_via_tid(tid) -> list:

    #dids = set()
    did_tids_file.seek(0)

    for line in did_tids_file:
        line_words = line.split()
        if any(word.startswith(tid) for word in line_words):
          yield line_words[0]
    #return dids

def tids_via_dids(dids):
    did_tids_file.seek(0)
    dids_set = set(dids)  # Convert the generator to a set for efficient membership testing
    for line in did_tids_file:
        line_words = line.split()
        if line_words[0] in dids_set:
          yield from (word.split(":")[0] for word in line_words[1:])

def dids_via_both(doct, docc) -> set:
    set1 = {value for value in doct}
    set2 = {value for value in docc}

    if(len(set1) > len(set2)):
      return set1.intersection(set2)
    else:
      return set2.intersection(set1)

def dids_via_either(doct, docc) -> set:
    set1 = set(doct)#{value for value in doct}
    set2 = set(docc)#{value for value in docc}

    return set1.union(set2)
```

My current implementation is using generators. I have also tried converting the sets to list and the opposite with no big difference in performance

Comment: I think you mean a roadblock, not a deadlock.

Comment: FYI, you can just write `set1 = set(doct)` you don't need the comprehension.

Comment: You don't need the calls to `float()`. `/` always returns a float.

Comment: your if the statement of `if(len(set1) > len(set2))` does nothing, the intersection of 2 sets will be the same, no matter how you put it. Also given the mentions of files, Your code might be I/O bound. How large are the files? why are you manually seeking to 0? can you provide the files to have a runnable example?

Comment: @OM2220 I have read in another post that "The time complexity of intersecting two sets is O(min(len(set1), len(set2))), so we should choose an order to do the intersections in, which minimises the sizes of the intermediate sets.", that's why I did it even though it had no difference in performance